# No restore points on system drive

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1

After perturbations with network scanner drivers, windows is not loading. It stalls at the stage of animating circularing dots. I.e. animation is alive, but final boot is not happening.

I don't understand, what for they did this animation? It should stop if computer hangs. And if it animating, then computer is not hanged and should boot. But it doesn't.

What to do?

**UPDATE**

If I go to safe mode and try to run `System restore`, I get a message "No restore points on system drive". I don't understand why? Previously Windows was creating restore points by default. Ok. Also it suggests to open `System protection`. If I click this, then is says, that "System protection" is available only in online operating system.

I.e. we have some chain of delirium messages here.

What to do?

**UPDATE 2**

If I am trying to repair from distribution disk, it says that disk, on which system is installed is blocked. The it says to unblock disk and try again.

I was not blocking anything, I am booting from DVD-ROM.

**UPDATE 3**

`UPDATE 2` was reported for case whe repair ran from boot distribution disk. If I run repair from hard drive repair menu, then it asks password and when I enter it, it asks to inserd idstribution disk. When I enter it, it says that disk is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Windows 8 disc and click on repair it ?

Comment: I have only 8.0 disk, while my system is 8.1. I was upgraded to 8.1 via network.

Comment: I think there is no problem if you use the Windows 8 disc. Have you checked that out ?

Comment: Will use it as last resort

Comment: @Devid finally I checked it and found it is totally mad